# Onsen UI issues 'white screen' angularJS code shows up

Tags: javascript, cordova, onsen-ui

My cordova app is not worthy any more.
It shows up angular expressions on application run.
shows white screen at times at launch
I think it might be issue of JS dependencies.
I posting my JS dependencies order

```
<!-- JS dependencies (order matters!) -->
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD5sCjiaGLF8i8zul_W4GBsnMBY9mZTdB4&libraries=places"></script>

    <!-- Cordova reference -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS dependencies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css" />
  <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/pace.theme.css"> -->
    <!-- CSP support mode (required for Windows Universal apps) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular/angular-csp.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css" />
```

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8orl.png)

Is this because of wrong order of the dependencies or internet problems or anything I'm missing or I could do to work it perfectly

Comment: Did you really put JSes before CSSes? If you did so, try to put CSSes first

Comment: So according to best practices, we should put CSSes before JSes. True Sir?

Comment: I put the css before JS, now the angular Code shows up. :(

Comment: according to OnsenUI custom components (for example `<ons-page>`) that registered from JSes which require CSSes, yes, you must put CSSes before JS. Please show your JS code and JS log (from dev tool) so we can go to better discussion.

Comment: I moved the CSSes above the JSes. But problem remains the same. I have linked script of google API at the end of the body. It still works fine on Wifi, but on 2g network it shows white screen for a long time.
And sorry cannot upload the code cause application has been build already code is too long to upload.

Comment: The only script loaded from online resource is google map API, as far I can see. Yes it takes quite some time to load, so as I did myself, I'd recommend you to load the script on demand when map is about to be shown. Here is an old post, but still usable: www.vijayjoshi.org/2010/01/19/how-to-dynamically-load-the-google-maps-javascript-api-on-demand-loading/

Comment: Awesome, I am going to try this will let you the results :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but this can be solved by doing 2 things.  1.) Increase the time the splash screen is shown via the config.xml file to about 5000 ms. 2.) In the `ons.ready()` function, add: `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

This shows the splashscreen, hiding the white screen as your libraries load, and then hides it when the app is ready.  This solved my problem.

Comment: I tried the same, believe me I made it upto 9000 ms. I shifted all the templates away from my main index.html. hiding the navigator splashscreen from the ons.ready is bad practice I think as first the splash Screen shows upto 5 sec and then Splash screen again flashes and fade out.

Comment: Odd that you are having these issues.  The aforementioned fix is directly from the Onsen team.  In my apps, this is how I implemented it and I never have the splash screen fading in or out.  It just shows and disappears once the app is loaded.  If you check out Dartitis in the google play store, that app implements the screens exactly like this.

Comment: Ok, then I guess the fade in fade out issue is not other problem to be solved. :(